# How to pass active user to repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created a logic to audit all database inserts/updates/deletes.
I did this overiding **SaveChanges** from **DBContext**.

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(DataContextConfiguration))]
public sealed class Conexao : DbContext
{
    public Conexao(): base("connectionString")
    {
        base.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        base.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        base.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
        base.Database.CommandTimeout = 120000;
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        /*
        audit logic goes here
        */
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

But I need to register the user that called this operation.
The problem is that my class is used in web and app contexts, so, acessing HttpContext to retrieve the active user its not a solution.

How can I pass a user to it?

I'm new to C# and MVC and i'm not familiarized to Services, Repositories, Interfaces, etc...
Please verbose your answer.

Comment: Add a field to `Conexao` for the user and set it wherever this object is being used?

Comment: Authorization should be dealt with on API level.

Comment: The current web principal is also assigned to the current thread principal.  You can use that, since you're always in a thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that by *active user* you meant the logged in user, you can access the userid (or username, or whatever else you store in your claims when you log in) from the current principal of the thread, like this:

```
var currnentPrincipal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;
var userId=int.Parse(currnentPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);
```

You can use this in your `SaveChanges()` override; note that it has no reference to the web related classes.

Another, more complicated solution could be to wrap the HttpContext into a service and inject that via an interface to the context (or the Unit-of-work or your repositories), but in my experience that's a lot more work than the benefits it yields.

Comment: This appear to fix part of my problem. I have a web based solution that the user can login, and this solution solves this, but I have another 3 console apps. In this console apps i need to force the user for each console, for example, Console 1 is equivalent to User 1 in the database, console 2 and 3 have diferent users in the database too. How can I force the login to this thread in my console app?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but if you want to do what I think you want to do, you can also set the Thread.CurrentPrincipal. When your console apps start, you can query the user from the db and assign the the Thread.CurrentPrincipal a ClaimsPrincipal which you construct manually from the user record.

Comment: Yessssssss...this solved my problem. Thank you very much @Akos.